# split strings using c language

Tags: c, string, split

I have a file which contains this lines :

```
0: 1(ab) 6(a)
1: 3(b) 4(a)
2: 5(a) 3(ab)
```

I want to split those lines to get the values, and store them somehow in an array or something else.

Any help !

`More Explanations`

The 0, 1, 2 are peaks of a graphe.

For the first peak 0, we have two arcs 1 and 6 an between parentheses the value of the arc.

Comment: Search for [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) or [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: read documentation of `fscanf`, might it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf seems to work alright as @Adeel suggests :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int peak, arc1, arc2;
    char v1[100], v2[100];
    scanf("%d: %d(%s %d(%s", &peak, &arc1, &v1, &arc2, &v2);
    v1[strlen(v1)-1] = 0; // clear the closing parentheses
    v2[strlen(v2)-1] = 0; // clear the closing parentheses

    printf("%d, %d, %s, %d, %s", peak, arc1, v1, arc2, v2);
}
```

The clearing is required because the strings are read 1 too far. This will work if the input doesn't have arbitrary spaces. For those cases strtok etc may be needed.

Tested :-

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>test.exe
0: 1(ab) 6(a)
```

Output :-

```
0, 1, ab, 6, a
```

Comment: In that case you need something better. Like what @joachim suggests